# How to add custom resolution for HyperV monitor using WinAPI

Tags: windows, winapi, display, screen-resolution

I want to add and set custom resolutions (modelines) for a HyperV monitor on an Azure VM

Read the docs and they said `ChangeDisplaySettings` API should do the trick. Tried it and the following code returns `The graphics mode is not supported`;

```c
void ChangeScreenResolution(int width, int height) {
    DEVMODE devMode = {};

    WINBOOL result =
        EnumDisplaySettingsA(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode);

    if (result == 0) {
        printf("EnumDisplaySettingsA Falied with code: %d\n", result);
        return;
    }

    DEVMODE *newMode = &devMode;

    newMode->dmPelsWidth = width;
    newMode->dmPelsHeight = height;
    newMode->dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

    LONG changeDispResult = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
        NULL, newMode, NULL, CDS_GLOBAL | CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | CDS_NORESET, NULL);


    LogChangeDispSettingsReturn(changeDispResult, "ChangeDisplayResolution");

    // According to the docs
    // To change the settings for more than one display at the same
    // time, first call ChangeDisplaySettingsEx for each device
    // individually to update the registry without applying the changes.
    // Then call ChangeDisplaySettingsEx once more, with a NULL device,
    // to apply the changes.
    LONG ret = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);

    LogChangeDispSettingsReturn(ret, "ChangeScreenResolution Again");
}
```

Here is the `LogChangeDispSettingsReturn` function I made for convenience

```c
void LogChangeDispSettingsReturn(LONG ret, char *funcName) {
    printf("%s: ", funcName);

    switch (ret) {
    case DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL:
        printf("The settings change was successful.\n");
        break;

    case DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW:
        printf("The settings change was unsuccessful because the "
               "system is DualView capable.\n");
        break;

    case DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS:
        printf("An invalid set of flags was passed in.\n");
        break;

    case DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE:
        printf("The graphics mode is not supported.\n");
        break;

    case DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM:
        printf("An invalid parameter was passed in. This can include "
               "an invalid flag or combination of flags.\n");
        break;

    case DISP_CHANGE_FAILED:
        printf("The display driver failed the specified graphics mode.\n");
        break;

    case DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED:
        printf("Unable to write settings to the registry.\n");
        break;

    case DISP_CHANGE_RESTART:
        printf("The computer must be restarted for the graphics mode "
               "to work.\n");
        break;
    };
}
```

Also found `QueryDisplayConfig` and `SetDisplayConfig` functions and thought about adding modelines to the `DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO *modeInfoArray` array returned by `QueryDisplayConfig` but apparently that's not allowed as I couldn't get it to work.

Also, I am not making these changes via an RDP client so display setting in the GUI are available to me, and hence I'm assuming the APIs should also be available.

Only adding a new mode does not work, if I use my `ChangeScreenResolution` function to change the resolution to something that I can see in the GUI, then the resolution change works.

Comment: HyperV usually requires additional configuration to support higher resolution. I would start from checking if vGPU supports this resolution at all. maybe this can be of any help to you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/341631/how-to-adjust-virtual-machine-display-resolution-t